# how to get this below list using spark rdd?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, sparkcore

List(1,2,3,4..100)==> List((1,2),(2,3),(3,4)...(100,101))==>List(3,5,7,....201)

****scala> x.map(x=>x,x+1).map(x=>x._1+x._2**)**
:26: error: too many arguments (2) for method map: (f: Int => B)(implicit bf: **scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom**[List[Int],B,That])That
x.map(x=>x,x+1).map(x=>x._1+x._2)

am trying to transform the 1 to 100 values but am getting the above error.Is there any issue with any the code?

Comment: Please [reformat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your question to make it clear what is code and what is your actual question

Comment: First "map" function need additional parentheses: x.map(x=>(x,x+1))

Comment: Sure..thanks pasha701

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your map function's return is incorrect.

try this:

```
input.map(x => (x,x+1)).map(x => x._1 + x._2)
```

Although, I don't see the need for two map functions when you can do it in one like this:

```
input.map(x => x + x + 1)
```

the above expression will also give you the same result.